# TMUX attach to a session with session number

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tmux

I want to attach to a `tmux` session using number. I have already created previous sessions without specifying name. When I use `tmux list-sessions` I see the following list:

```
0: 1 windows (created Wed Aug 26 19:16:40 2020) [117x44]
1: 1 windows (created Wed Aug 26 19:22:03 2020) [170x48]
2: 1 windows (created Wed Aug 26 22:35:12 2020) [185x58]
3: 1 windows (created Thu Aug 27 12:32:57 2020) [164x38]
5: 1 windows (created Thu Aug 27 13:17:51 2020) [120x29]
```

So they don't have any specific name. I want to attach to session [1].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The number before the `:` *is* the specific name actually, tmux auto-named your sessions because you didn't provide a name.

To attach to session [1] you'd go:

```
tmux attach -t 1
```

---

You can also rename a session if you want to be able to know what it contains when you `tmux list-sessions`:

```
tmux rename-session -t <current-name> <new-name>
```

For example - to rename session 1 to session abcd:

```
tmux rename-session -t 1 abcd
```